# Testng, parallelization error in @AfterMethod. Java + Testng + Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, testng

There is @AfterMethod, which checks the number of numbers in two checks after each test method, when the document is created, the numbers in the checks change. @AfterMethod first checks check_1 and then check_2, but during parallelization it turns out that the number from check_1 is written to memory, and while the transition to check_2 is performed, another test changes the values ​​of both checks. I tried adding "synchronized" to the method, but it didn't help.

Comment: Selenium sounds like UI tests which are integration tests which are by definition not parallelizable in general.. apart from that there is no code example etc more or less no detailed information...how should someone being able to help here?

Comment: Can you add some code? Preferably the minimum representative example without the code that is not relevant to the issue.

Comment: please share code and screenshot, that would be more helpful !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.